# Android: How to load saved data from another class?

Tags: android, reference, save

I've saved an int when a button is saved (in the upgrade class), and the int is called in another activity (the play class). But whenever I replay the app, I first need to go to the upgrade activity before the i go to the play activity, otherwise the integers I have saved aren't loaded properly.

```
public class Play extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

MKZSurface ourSurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourSurfaceView = new MKZSurface(this);
    ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(ourSurfaceView);
    MYU = Upgrades.mYU;
    BU = Upgrades.BU;
    MBU = Upgrades.mBU;
    RU = Upgrades.RU;
    MRU = Upgrades.mRU;
}
```

And in the upgrades class I have saved these ints with a value using SharedPreferences. How do I load the data with the saved ints without the need to going to the upgrades page first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieved your data without going back to Upgrades page if you have saved them using SharedPreferences. Use something like below to retrieve your data.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
int indData = prefs.getInt(MY_INT, 0);
```

0 is the default value in case you haven't saved any values.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Play activity firstly and check if saved value != DEFAULT_VALUE
otherwise go to upgrade activity and save new value